# Unable to save configuration of Teams connector

Tags: microsoft-teams

Past two days, I have been trying to configure MS Teams connector following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-webhooks-connectors/7-exercise-o365-connectors

I configured the connector via Connectors Developer Dashboard.
Then I tried both, cloning and reconfiguring this sample:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/Teams/60%20Webhooks%20O365%20Connectors/Demos/03-o365-connector

and also bootstrapping the project via `yo teams`, following the tutorial step-by-step.

After building the project and serving it via ngrok, I can sideload the connector into Teams (tried both, desktop app and web), it successfully brings me to configuration page, but never allows me to save the connector settings. I always get this error:
`Unable to save “My First Teams Connector” connector configuration. Please try again.`

I adapted the code and debugged it to see, that the call to `/api/connector/connect` succeeds and `saveEvent.notifySuccess()` is called.

Then I noticed, that right after saving the connector via browser, this error appears in the console:

```
{
  "seq": 1597590187271,
  "timestamp": 1597593891957,
  "flightSettings": {
    "Name": "ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
    "AriaSDKToken": "d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033",
    "SPAEnabled": true,
    "ClassificationFilterEnabled": true,
    "ClientRoutingEnabled": true,
    "EnableYammerGroupOption": true,
    "EnableFadeMessage": false,
    "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList": false,
    "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList": false,
    "DevPortalSPAEnabled": true,
    "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage": false,
    "DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage": true
  },
  "status": 500,
  "clientType": "SkypeSpaces",
  "connectorType": "f39fe17c-6452-4879-b692-a93d73684348",
  "name": "handleMessageError"
}
```

Any idea what could be incorrectly configured, or whether there is a place to check for more descriptive error? Log of desktop Teams was not helpful either.

ConnectorID: f39fe17c-6452-4879-b692-a93d73684348

Comment: Did you add valid domains in Connector Portal also did you added the base url? Could you please try this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-outgoing-webhook)

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT in Microsoft Learn, it is stated, that you do not have to (re)configure valid domains as the manifest is read from the sideloaded app (where the valid ngrok domains are set during build automatically). Nevertheless, yes, I also tried to set the valid domains directly in Connector Portal - no change. What do you mean by _base url_? I filled in all required fileds in the Connector Portal.
Regarding the sample - this is not about outgoing webooks, I am trying a connector.

Comment: Could you please share your connector dashboard screen shot and manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what really helped me in the end for that particular tutorial:

1. run `gulp ngrok-serve`
2. configure the connector following the tutorial (with valid domains; excluding protocol) on `Connectors Developer Dashboard`
3. extract the content of packaged connector
4. adapt extracted `manifest.json` with newly created connector ID (both occurrences)
5. repackage the connector as zip
6. upload to Teams & configure it

Comment: Have you figured what have you did wrong to get the error of the initial message?

Comment: Stuck here and cannot resolve. Any idea what you did to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I filled the **valid domains** field with `xxxxxxxx.ngrok.io` which is the domain of my configuration page.

Be careful, if you update an existing connector, apparently these changes needs time to be taken into account. To be sure, you can create a fresh new connector.

[image: teams connector form]

Comment: I first marked your answer as accepted, but as this on it's own did not help me to get it running, I posted a step-by-step guide, which did the trick for me. Thanks anyways!